# Write an xml file in Sharepoint using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, xml, sharepoint-2010

I have a website that I created in Visual Studio. I have stored some structural information in an xml file which I write using code behind C# file. Now I have to migrate this whole project to SharePoint. I am new to SharePoint and I need a way to write the xml file and store that back to server. Is it possible to do it with JavaScript? If not, is there another way?

**EDIT** I forgot to mention I want to modify an existing xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this way
1)Add a Feature to your project sharepoint project
2)Add an event reciever, in the feature.cs file u can create XML file

```
    public class Feature1EventReceiver : SPFeatureReceiver
    {
       public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {

        // Get the Context
        SPSite Site = (SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent;
        //Get the Web Address
        SPWeb Web = Site.OpenWeb();

        //Create a Path to Microsoft Shared/14 

        //string serverPath = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(string.Empty);
        string serverPath =         "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\wss\\VirtualDirectories\\38118\\config";
        // Changes yhe folder permission to the grant access to all chat users 
        FolderACL(serverPath);
        //Create the Congig file 
        CreateConfigFile(serverPath);

    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Changes yhe folder permission to the grant access to all chat users 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    public static void FolderACL(String path)
    {
        DirectorySecurity Psec = Directory.GetAccessControl(path);
        SecurityIdentifier Peveryone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
        Psec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(Peveryone, FileSystemRights.Modify | FileSystemRights.Synchronize, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow));
        Directory.SetAccessControl(path, Psec);
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Method which Created the Config file 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path"></param>
    public static void CreateConfigFile(String path)
    {
        //Use an xml Writer
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(path + "/Config.xml"))
        {
            //Start the Xml Document
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            //Create Root element
            writer.WriteStartElement("Root");
            //Write Element in the root element
            writer.WriteElementString("element", "abcd");
            writer.WriteElementString("element", "efgh");
           //End the root element
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            //End the Xml Document
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I want to modify an existing xml file. Can I use **XDocument** class here instead of **XmlWriter**.

Answer (score 0):

Ya, then u can use Xdocument

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
   doc.Load("source path");
  // Make changes to the document.
   XmlTextWriter xtw = new XmlTextWriter("destination path", Encoding.UTF8);
```